# Grails Excel Importer Validation with Excel, Excel 2007 & CSV Importer Using Apache POI

Tags: excel, grails

Im using the plugin mentioned in the title to import an excel spreadsheet and all is working well but I've read and reread the grails documentation and can't figure out how to set up my validation map to auto fill null cells with my chosen defaults.

Here is my column mapping:

```
Map ACCOUNT_RECORD_COLUMN_MAP = [
            sheet:'Sheet1',
            startRow: 1,
            columnMap: [
                //Col, Map-Key
                'A':'uniqueId',
                'B':'accountId',
                'C':'type',
                'D':'insurance',
                'E':'currencyType',
                'F':'amount',
                'G':'upSerDel',
                'H':'generalComments' 
            ]
        ]
```

and here is the validation map I'd like to apply:

```
Map propertyConfigurationMap = [
            type:([expectedType: ExpectedPropertyType.StringType, defaultValue:""],
            amount:([expectedType: ExpectedPropertyType.FloatType, defaultValue:-1.0))
        ]
```

I can get a list fine by doing:

```
List accountRecordList = excelImportService.columns(workbook, ACCOUNT_RECORD_COLUMN_MAP)
```

but ofcourse this doesn't apply the validation map. I can't seem to figure out the relationship between the different methods to see how to apply this validation map to my needs. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The source file of [ExcelImportService](https://github.com/jbarmash/grails-excel-import/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugins/excelimport/ExcelImportService.groovy) says:

```
def columns(Workbook workbook, Map config, ImportCellCollector pcc = null, propertyConfigurationMap = [:], int lastRow = -1) {
```

Notice that the second parameter would be "ACCOUNT_RECORD_COLUMN_MAP" and the fourth "propertyConfigurationMap". You must call the method this way:

```
List accountRecordList = excelImportService.columns(workbook, ACCOUNT_RECORD_COLUMN_MAP, null, propertyConfigurationMap)
```